# Can I rollback/abort a transaction if no rows were inserted?

Tags: mysql, transaction

I have a transaction in which I want to do something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO table1 (...)
SELECT ... FROM table 2;

... if select count(*) from table1 returns 0 abort/rollback ...

COMMIT;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  In MySQL, you can only use `if` in stored procedures, so this is typically done client side.  Pseudo-code:

```
int rows = db.ExecuteScalar(
    "start transaction; " +
    "insert into table1 (col1) select col1 from table2; " +
    "select count(*) from table1");
if (rows == 0) {
    db.ExecuteNonQuery("abort transaction");
} else {
    db.ExecuteNonQuery("commit transaction");
}
```

Rolling back a transaction that did nothing (inserted no rows) doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but I'm assuming you simplified reality for this question.

Comment: Like Andomar said you may have simplified your example: but in simple cases you can use the affected_rows function (in a stored procedure or client side) to get the number of rows the INSERT query did. You may not need to do count(*).